# Meteor Server unable to locate `findUserByEmail`

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

Running latest version of Meteor. I have added the `accounts-password` package but it seems Meteor server cannot detect any of the methods defined in it, specifically while accessing `Accounts.findUserByEmail` and `Accounts.findUserByUsername`.

All methods on the client side work as expected though.

This issue has been raised in the [Meteor forums](https://forums.meteor.com/t/accounts-error-object-has-no-method-finduserbyemail/11725) as well, but no one has been able to solve or troubleshoot this.

I have the following packages installed-

```
accounts-password        1.1.1* Password support for accounts
accounts-twitter         1.0.4* Login service for Twitter accounts
accounts-ui              1.1.5* Simple templates to add login widgets to an app
kadira:react-layout      1.2.0* Layout Manager for React with SSR Support
meteor-platform          1.2.2* Include a standard set of Meteor packages in your app
meteorhacks:flow-router  1.18.0* Carefully Designed Client Side Router for Meteor
meteorhacks:kadira       2.23.1* Performance Monitoring for Meteor
npm-container            1.2.0+ Contains all your npm dependencies
react                    0.1.10* Everything you need to use React with Meteor.
service-configuration    1.0.4* Manage the configuration for third-party services
twitter                  1.1.4* Twitter OAuth flow
underscore               1.0.3* Collection of small helpers: _.map, _.each, ...
```

Here is my Meteor versions file:

```
accounts-base@1.2.0
accounts-oauth@1.1.5
accounts-password@1.1.1
accounts-twitter@1.0.4
accounts-ui@1.1.5
accounts-ui-unstyled@1.1.7
autoupdate@1.2.1
babel-compiler@5.6.15
babel-runtime@0.1.3
base64@1.0.3
binary-heap@1.0.3
blaze@2.1.2
blaze-tools@1.0.3
boilerplate-generator@1.0.3
callback-hook@1.0.3
check@1.0.5
coffeescript@1.0.6
cosmos:browserify@0.4.0
ddp@1.1.0
deps@1.0.7
ejson@1.0.6
email@1.0.6
fastclick@1.0.3
geojson-utils@1.0.3
html-tools@1.0.4
htmljs@1.0.4
http@1.1.0
id-map@1.0.3
jquery@1.11.3_2
json@1.0.3
jsx@0.1.6
kadira:react-layout@1.2.0
launch-screen@1.0.2
less@1.0.14
livedata@1.0.13
localstorage@1.0.3
logging@1.0.7
meteor@1.1.6
meteor-platform@1.2.2
meteorhacks:flow-router@1.18.0
meteorhacks:kadira@2.23.1
meteorhacks:meteorx@1.3.1
minifiers@1.1.5
minimongo@1.0.8
mobile-status-bar@1.0.3
mongo@1.1.0
mongo-livedata@1.0.8
npm-bcrypt@0.7.8_2
npm-container@1.2.0
oauth@1.1.4
oauth1@1.1.4
observe-sequence@1.0.6
ordered-dict@1.0.3
random@1.0.3
react@0.1.10
react-meteor-data@0.1.6
react-runtime@0.13.3_6
react-runtime-dev@0.13.3_5
react-runtime-prod@0.13.3_4
reactive-dict@1.1.0
reactive-var@1.0.5
reload@1.1.3
retry@1.0.3
routepolicy@1.0.5
service-configuration@1.0.4
session@1.1.0
sha@1.0.3
spacebars@1.0.6
spacebars-compiler@1.0.6
srp@1.0.3
templating@1.1.1
tracker@1.0.7
twitter@1.1.4
ui@1.0.6
underscore@1.0.3
url@1.0.4
webapp@1.2.0
webapp-hashing@1.0.3
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Would you mind showing your Meteor versions file? I tried to create a whole new Meteor project with only `accounts-password` package being added and everything is working fine.

Comment: How about running a  `meteor update` and check whether the problem has been solved? I have exactly the same packages like yours in my newly created Meteor project and the only difference is in their versions.

Comment: Care to share the relevant code to help us reproduce the problem?

Comment: @nchenbang Looks like the update did the trick! Thank you so much!!

Comment: @nchenbang If you could add this as an answer and possibly even explain why such a condition could come into being, that'll be great!